# How can I detect refresh page and routes change in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have to call an specific function (`componentsHandler`) every time that the route changes or the page is refreshed.

This function is responsible to deal with some components states

```
componentsHandler(menuItem, event) {
    switch (menuItem) {
      case '/':
        this.headerTitleHandler('Search')
        this.searchBarHandler(true)
        break
      case '/dashboard':
        this.headerTitleHandler('Dashboard')
        break
      case '/administration':
        this.headerTitleHandler('Admin')
        this.searchBarHandler(false)
        this.searchBarInfoHandler(false)
        break
      default:          
    }
  }
```

So, when the route changes I call `componentsHandler` function using `componentDidUpdate`:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.componentsHandler(this.props.location.pathname)
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I refresh the page, componentDidUpdate doesn't detect it and the `componentsHandler` function is not called.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: does it work when you click manually ?

Comment: @NikhilPatil yes. It doesnt works if I refresh the page

Comment: are you using used react-router ? for routing

Comment: yep..sorry for didnt write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `componentsHandler` function in `componentDidMount`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.componentsHandler(this.props.location.pathname);
  }
```

Comment: componentDidMount() called only once !
I think it won't work.

Comment: @NikhilPatil When we refresh or route is changed by users, the component is destroyed and created again when you visit again. That means componentDidMount should be called every time when you visit by route or refresh.

Comment: yes you are right whenever component is rendered componenetDidMount() get's called. My Bad!

Answer (score 0):

On refresh your app is rendered from scratch. You need a handler for `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` (or just `useEffect` if you use hooks)

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.componentsHandler(this.props.location.pathname)
  }


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.componentsHandler(this.props.location.pathname)
    }
  }
```